# zip, but keep the original collection items

Tags: kotlin

I have 2 collections: `[11, 22, 33, 44]`, `[A, B]`. I'd like to merge them, like `zip`, but don't truncate the resulting collection to the shortest one. So the result should be

```
[11 -> A, 22 -> B, 33 -> null, 44 -> null]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
first.mapIndexed{ index, id -> id to second.getOrNull(index) }
```

Answer (score 3):

In case you don't know which collection is larger:

```
(0 until Math.max(first.size, second.size)).map { first.getOrNull(it) to second.getOrNull(it) }
```

Comment: Neat.  (Note that if the result were a map, not a list, it probably wouldn't be a good idea to handle the second list being longer: many map implementations don't allow null keys; and those that do can't map them to more than one value.)